# Ruling out AzureDatabricks and microsoftwindowsdesktop from Azure policy

Tags: azure-policy

I'm currently using this build in policy to install Qualys to our servers: https://www.azadvertizer.net/azpolicyadvertizer/13ce0167-8ca6-4048-8e6b-f996402e3c1b.html

```
{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "Configure machines to receive a vulnerability assessment provider",
    "policyType": "BuiltIn",
    "mode": "Indexed",
    "description": "Azure Defender includes vulnerability scanning for your machines at no extra cost. You don't need a Qualys license or even a Qualys account - everything's handled seamlessly inside Security Center. When you enable this policy, Azure Defender automatically deploys the Qualys vulnerability assessment provider to all supported machines that don't already have it installed.",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Security Center",
      "version": "4.0.0"
    },
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "DeployIfNotExists",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
      },
      "vaType": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Vulnerability assessment provider type",
          "description": "Select the vulnerability assessment solution to provision to machines."
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "default",
          "mdeTvm"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "default"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "anyof": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
          },
          {
            "allOf": [
              {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines"
              },
              {
                "field": "tags",
                "notContainsKey": "MDFCSecurityConnector"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
        "details": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Security/assessments",
          "name": "ffff0522-1e88-47fc-8382-2a80ba848f5d",
          "evaluationDelay": "PT60M",
          "existenceCondition": {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.code",
                "equals": "NotApplicable"
              },
              {
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.code",
                    "equals": "Healthy"
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.cause",
                    "equals": "[parameters('vaType')]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "deployment": {
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
              "template": {
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                "parameters": {
                  "vmName": {
                    "type": "String"
                  },
                  "resourceType": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "vaType": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                },
                "variables": {
                  "resourceNameAndVaType": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/Microsoft.Security/', parameters('vaType'))]"
                },
                "resources": [
                  {
                    "condition": "[equals(toLower(parameters('resourceType')), toLower('microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'))]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/providers/serverVulnerabilityAssessments",
                    "name": "[variables('resourceNameAndVaType')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-01-01"
                  },
                  {
                    "condition": "[equals(toLower(parameters('resourceType')), toLower('microsoft.hybridcompute/machines'))]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines/providers/serverVulnerabilityAssessments",
                    "name": "[variables('resourceNameAndVaType')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2020-01-01"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "parameters": {
                "vmName": {
                  "value": "[field('name')]"
                },
                "resourceType": {
                  "value": "[field('type')]"
                },
                "vaType": {
                  "value": "[parameters('vaType')]"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "roleDefinitionIds": [
            "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fb1c8493-542b-48eb-b624-b4c8fea62acd"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/13ce0167-8ca6-4048-8e6b-f996402e3c1b",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "13ce0167-8ca6-4048-8e6b-f996402e3c1b"
}
```

Currently policy run against `type = Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` and because of that policy installs Qualys to our Windows Desktops (which we do not want) and AzureDatabricks (fails because it not supported). This leads to pretty red compliance page.

My goal would create custom policy out of that were these would be ruled out based of publisher.

```
Publisher: AzureDatabricks
Publisher: MicrosoftWindowsDesktop
```

I think ruling out should be done something like this but have not clue where I should put this in the policy

```
"not": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
          "in": [
"MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
"AzureDatabricks"
]
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think ruling out should be done something like this but have not clue where I should put this in the policy.

In order to add below code in **Policy** to exclude  **MicrosoftWindowsDesktop** and **AzureDatabricks**

```
"not": {
        "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
          "in": [
"MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
"AzureDatabricks"
]
        }
      }
```

This below  **Azure policy** will assess the security of **virtual machines** and **hybrid machines** in **Azure environment**. If the machines do not meet the specified security standards, the policy will deploy a **vulnerability assessment solution** to the machines. The policy will only be executed if the specified conditions are met.

Here is the updated **policy** include with the above code.

```
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
            "in": [
              "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop",
              "AzureDatabricks"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "anyof": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
            },
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "type",
                  "equals": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines"
                },
                {
                  "field": "tags",
                  "notContainsKey": "MDFCSecurityConnector"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Security/assessments",
        "name": "ffff0522-1e88-47fc-8382-2a80ba848f5d",
        "evaluationDelay": "PT60M",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.code",
              "equals": "NotApplicable"
            },
            {
              "allOf": [
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.code",
                  "equals": "Healthy"
                },
                {
                  "field": "Microsoft.Security/assessments/status.cause",
                  "equals": "[parameters('vaType')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "template": {
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "parameters": {
                "vmName": {
                  "type": "String"
                },
                "resourceType": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "vaType": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "variables": {
                "resourceNameAndVaType": "[concat(parameters('vmName'), '/Microsoft.Security/', parameters('vaType'))]"
              },
              "resources": [
                {
                  "condition": "[equals(toLower(parameters('resourceType')), toLower('microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'))]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/providers/serverVulnerabilityAssessments",
                  "name": "[variables('resourceNameAndVaType')]",
                  "apiVersion": "2020-01-01"
                },
                {
                  "condition": "[equals(toLower(parameters('resourceType')), toLower('microsoft.hybridcompute/machines'))]",
                  "type": "Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines/providers/serverVulnerabilityAssessments",
                  "name": "[variables('resourceNameAndVaType')]",
                  "apiVersion": "2020-01-01"
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "vmName": {
                "value": "[field('name')]"
              },
              "resourceType": {
                "value": "[field('type')]"
              },
              "vaType": {
                "value": "[parameters('vaType')]"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/9980e02c-c2be-4d73-94e8-173b1dc7cf3c",
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/1c0163c0-47e6-4577-8991-ea5c82e286e4",
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/fb879df8-f326-4884-b1cf-06f3ad86be52",
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/602da2ba-a5c2-41da-b01d-5360126ab525",
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/a6333a3e-0164-44c3-b281-7a577aff287f"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "DeployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
    },
    "vaType": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Vulnerability assessment provider type",
        "description": "Select the vulnerability assessment solution to provision to machines."
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "default",
        "mdeTvm"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "default"
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Refer: [Manage AWS assessments and standards](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/defender-for-cloud/how-to-manage-aws-assessments-standards.md)

Comment: Hello, seems that this policy is not now working for hybrid vms (Azure vms works fine) but it is ruling out databricks and desktops.

Comment: Policy applies to virtual machines (VMs) and hybrid machines that do not have the "MDFCSecurityConnector" tag. The policy also excludes VMs with image publishers "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop" and "AzureDatabricks.